# How to close this menu on any click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So far I managed to successfully open and close the menu via the menu-icon. But I would like to close it on any click. I am overwhelmed about how to tackle this. I tried to add a click event listener on window/document/header/nav ... but it seems to immediatly close the menu, before anything gets select. How would you approach this?

```js
let nav = document.querySelector(".header__nav");

function toggleNavOn() {
  if (nav.style.visibility === "") {
    nav.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    nav.style.visibility = "";
  }
  navToggle.classList.toggle("header__nav_toggle--toggled")
}

let navToggle = document.querySelector(".header__nav_toggle");
navToggle.addEventListener("click", toggleNavOn);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --color-white: #fffff0;
  --color-black: #000;
  --color-primary: #5f5e63;
  --color-primary-light: #8c8b90;
  --color-primary-dark: #353439;
  --color-primary-dark-2: #131313;
  --color-secondary: #ca3722;
  --color-secondary-light: #ff6a4c;
  --color-secondary-dark: #920000;
  --cells: 40;
  --cellSize: calc(100vw / var(--cells));
}

.header {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 40;
  grid-column: 1 / span 40;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.9rem 1.8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0.625rem 0.625rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  box-shadow: 0 0.9rem 1.8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0.625rem 0.625rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  padding: 1.1rem 1.4rem;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--color-primary-dark-2);
}

.header__container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 11;
}

.header__container_logo {
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header__logo_link {
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
  -ms-flex-positive: 2;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.header__logo_img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 1.3rem;
  width: 2.6rem;
}

.header__nav_toggle {
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}

.header__nav_toggle span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__nav_toggle span::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 6px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-white);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.header__nav_toggle span::after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 12px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-white);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.header__nav_toggle--toggled span::before {
  top: 13px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.header__nav_toggle--toggled span::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.header__nav_link:hover,
.header__logo_link:hover,
.header__logo_img:hover,
.header__nav_toggle:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.header__nav_link {
  display: none;
  color: var(--color-white);
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

.header__nav {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: -0.9rem;
  padding-top: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-dark);
}

.header__nav_link {
  display: block;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  -o-border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), var(--color-primary-dark), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1;
  border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(var(--color-primary-dark)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), var(--color-primary-dark), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__container">
    <div class="header__container_logo">
      <a class="header__logo_link" href="#"><img class="header__logo_img" src="img/vtol-logo.svg" alt="Vtol Logo"></a>
      <a class="header__nav_toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <nav class="header__nav" id="nav-bar">
      <a class="header__nav_link" href="#video-container">Watch</a>
      <a class="header__nav_link" href="#features">Features</a>
      <a class="header__nav_link" href="#about">About</a>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't see your code closes the `header`, by you term where is `menu`?

Comment: @Manjuboyz I removed the bit which was supposed to close it, because it didn't work and was a mess. By menu I meant the nav, when it is toggled and overlaying the whole site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand why you're seeing the menu close immediately when adding a click event handler to window/document/(whatever parent element), it is necessary to start with a discussion of event capturing and bubbling. The order goes capturing -> click captured -> propagating.. You click an element and it is captured first on window and goes all the way down the DOM to the most specific DOM element. It then "bubbles" back up firing event handlers along the way. Here is some more information on the subject: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

What is happening in your scenario is that the click event on the menu is triggering handlers not just on that element but every parent as well. One possible solution is to add an `event.stopPropagation()` to your menu click event handler so that a click event there doesn't bubble up to whatever parent DOM element you attach the "close menu" functionality to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I came across stopPropagation() as well, but I read that it might not be good practice to use that, because it might have "unintended side effects" (that the bubbling event might be needed). Do you disagree with that in general, or would you say in such a menu toggle case it's generally safe? This is the article that kept me from going down that route: https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the interesting read. That article seems to be advocating for an event handler on `document` and taking a look at `event.target` to determine what it should do so it's all centralized a la event delegation. My philosophy is you should code for the needs of today while at the same time writing it in such a way that it isn't hard to change later as needs change. What approach do you think "future you" will be able to read and understand better later? At the end of the day, if you never use that bubbled menu click event for anything, it doesn't matter which approach you choose.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at 'focus' and 'blur' events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Comment: Why would you use these events? (a first google search makes me think maybe accessibility?) And how would you use these for a menu, since the example on MDN is for fields .... ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/f21vnq5s/1/

You should first set height of menu then in document check click if in header or not

It should be work with jquery

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var searchcontainer = $(".header");

    if (!searchcontainer.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && searchcontainer.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
           nav.style.visibility = "";
    }
});
```